# Error al guardar registro de formulario

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Al momento de guardar un registro de formulario me salta el siguiente error, se refiere a una key foranea pero en la tabla prestador_seguro la id primaria es idprestador, en la tabla reasignaciones es key foranea, no entiendo el error porque en las tablas de la base de datos los campos estan correctos. Yo creo que es algo referido al try del controller de la function store.

**"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (dbsgp.reasignaciones, CONSTRAINT fk_Reasignaciones_Prestador_Seguro FOREIGN KEY (idprestador) REFERENCES prestador_seguro (idprestador) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) (SQL: insert into reasignaciones (idpmed, idprestador, Medicamento, Tipo_Solicitud, total, fecha_hora, estado) values (1_Pedro_Diaz, Casmu, Pirfenidona, Ordenanza, ?, 2019-06-20 10:16:52, A)) ◀"**

Aqui dejo una captura de la seccion de mi sistema donde surge el error, utilizo dos campos para seleccionar datos de la tabla prestador_seguro, uno es Prestador/Seguro, el otro Custodia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui dejo la function store del controller:

```
 public function store (ReasignacionFormRequest $request)
    {
        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $reasignacion=new Reasignacion;
            $reasignacion->idpmed=$request->get('idpmed');
            $reasignacion->idprestador=$request->get('idprestador')[0];
            $reasignacion->Medicamento=$request->get('Medicamento');
            $reasignacion->Tipo_Solicitud=$request->get('Tipo_Solicitud');
            $reasignacion->total=$request->get('total');

            $mytime = Carbon::now('America/Montevideo');
            $reasignacion->fecha_hora=$mytime->toDateTimeString();
            $reasignacion->estado='A';
            $reasignacion->save();

            $idexcedente = $request->get('idexcedente');
            $idprestador = $request->get('idprestador')[1];
            $cantidad = $request->get('cantidad');

            $cont = 0;

            while($cont < count($idexcedente)){
                $detallerea = new Detallerea();
                $detallerea->idreasignacion= $reasignacion->idreasignacion; 
                $detallerea->idexcedente= $idexcedente[$cont];
                $detallerea->idprestador= $idprestador[$cont];
                $detallerea->cantidad= $cantidad[$cont];
                $detallerea->save();
                $cont=$cont+1;            
            }

            DB::commit();

        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            dd($e->getMessage());
            DB::rollback();
        }

        return Redirect::to('reasignaciones');
```

En caso de que deba subir algo mas del codigo, favor de avisarme.

Agreo imagen de las tablas involucradas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ACTUALIZACION

**Creo que el error se encuentra en el siguiente fragmento de codigo js de la view create:**

```
function agregar()
          {

            idexcedente=$("#pidexcedente option:selected").text();
            idprestador=$("#custodia option:selected").text();
            cantidad=$("#pcantidad").val();
            stock=$("#pstock").val();

            if (cantidad!="" && cantidad>0)
            {
                if (parseInt(stock)>=parseInt(cantidad))
                {

                    total=total+parseInt(cantidad);

                    var fila='<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="idexcedente[]" value="'+idexcedente+'">'+idexcedente+'</td><td><input type="hidden" name="idprestador[]" value="'+idprestador+'">'+idprestador+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td></tr>';
                    cont++;
                    limpiar();
                    $("#total").html("Comp/Amp:  " + total);
                    evaluar();
                    $('#detalles').append(fila);   
                }
                else
                {
                    alert ('La cantidad a reasignar supera el stock');
                }

            }
            else
            {
                alert("Error al ingresar el detalle de reasignacion, revise los datos del excedente");
            }
          }
```

Comment: El error  te dice que estas violando la regla al insertar en la tabla ,eso puede que pase por tres cosas una  estas tratando de insertar una primary key repetida o estas insertando un tipo de dato que no deberías en el primary key o estas tratando de insertar en una foreing key un numero que no extiste en la tabla principal por lo cual no puede relacionar el registro

Answer (score 0):

mira tu insert
insert into reasignaciones (idpmed, idprestador, Medicamento, Tipo_Solicitud, total, fecha_hora, estado) values (1_Pedro_Diaz, Casmu, Pirfenidona, Ordenanza, ?, 2019-06-20 10:16:52, A)
Entonces segun tu diagrama

los primeros 3 campos qu insertas son
1_Pedro_Diaz, Casmu, Pirfenidona
y deberias insertar los 3 id correspondientes 
en reasignaciones aunque Tipo_Solicitud es un varchar tenes que insertar los correspondiente identificadores de las otras tablas.
ejemplo tabla 1.
id nombre
1  1_Pedro_Diaz
2  juan perez

tabla 2 
id nombre
1 Casmu
2 casME
tabla 3
Tipo_Solicitud nombre
primera   solicitud 1
Ordenanza solicitud 2
insert into reasignaciones (idpmed, idprestador, Medicamento, Tipo_Solicitud, total, fecha_hora, estado) values (1, 1, Pirfenidona, Ordenanza, ?, 2019-06-20 10:16:52, A)

Comment: Lo que busco insertar es el nombre del prestador, no su id, alli en el insert donde aparecen esos datos agregados, me aparece el nombre del prestador que es Casmu. Quizas sea ese el error, pero es en el controller que sucede?¿

Comment: Lo logico seria que insertes los id y con esos id insertados despues recuperar el nombre del prestador, pero esto sin ver el diseño de tu db, pasa si podes un diagrama o como esta armada tu db.

Comment: Agregue una imagen de las tablas involucradas de la db

Comment: Creo que el error se encuentra en el codigo js de la vista create, subi el codigo al post.